# Removing inner nodes with particular properties

Tags: xml, xslt

I am very new XSLTs and am having trouble trying to delete node's that contain a certain attributes in multiple nodes.  I don't really know the terminology (which makes finding the appropriate answer on the internet really difficult) so the code below will probably explain what I am looking for better than I can.

Original:

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<pages>
   <page id="main" default="true">
      <tabs>
         <tab id="login" default="true"/>
         <tab id="picture" default="true"/>
         <tab id="password"/>
      </tabs>
   <page id="secondary" default="true">
      <tabs>
         <tab id="pin" default="true"/>
         <tab id="picture" default="true"/>
      </tabs>
   </page>
   <page id="logout" default="true">
      <tabs>
         <tab id="goodbye"/>
         <tab id="login" default="true"/>
      </tabs>
   </page>
</pages>
```

Goal:  I would like to go through and remove all the picture elements.

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<pages>
   <page id="main" default="true">
      <tabs>
         <tab id="login" default="true"/>
         <tab id="password"/>
      </tabs>
   <page id="secondary" default="true">
      <tabs>
         <tab id="pin" default="true"/>
      </tabs>
   </page>
   <page id="logout" default="true">
      <tabs>
         <tab id="goodbye"/>
         <tab id="login" default="true"/>
      </tabs>
   </page>
</pages>
```

I have an xslt but it doesn't do what I want, so I am leaving below what I think an xslt that can do this would somewhat resemble.  My thoughts are I need to go into every page so don't provide a specific name, and then once we get into the tab look for a picture id if it is there...don't copy it...otherwise copy everything as usual.

```
<xsl:template match="p:pages/p:page/p:tabs/p:tab>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:if test=not("picture")>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Also, if anyone has a good recommendation for learning the basics (or at least terminology of XSLT), it would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: The xml is not well-formed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following stylesheet would do

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tab[@id='picture']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It has two templates - one generic which just recursively copies the input document - and one specific for `tab` elements with a picture id which does not produce any output, therefore effectively removing those elements.

Comment: Ah! DUH. Thank you very much!